# Diagonalization argument for convergence in distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

Let $Z_{n, N}$ be a sequence of random variable such that, for any fixed $N$, this sequence of variables converges in distribution to a variable $Z$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. There exists a sequence $N(n)$ that goes to infinity ($N(n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$) such that $Z_{n, N(n)}$ converges to $Z$ in distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$? How to construct the sequence $N(n)$ and prove the convergence in distribution of the resulting random variables $Z_{n, N(n)}$?

---

*A little bit of context:* An argument similar to the one above is used in Terence Tao, "Topics in Random Matrix Theory" [book](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/topics-in-random-matrix-theory/) under the name of *"diagonalization argument"*. In Section 2.2.1, the argument is used to show the possibility of considering bounded random variables to prove the central limit theorem without loss of generality. There $N$ is the upper bound for the variables and it is assumed that since central limit theorem yield $Z_{n, N} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, for any fixed $N$, it hold that $Z_{n, N(n)} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ for some sequence of bounds $N(n)$ dependent on $n$.
.

Comment: Take $N(m)=1$ for all $m$.  Then the result trivially holds.  I think you want to make the problem nontrivial by requiring $N(m)\rightarrow \infty$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Good point. Yes, I am interested in the case $N(m)\rightarrow \infty$... I fixed the question to make it more clear

Comment: It would be easier to first understand this in the context of sequences of real numbers (rather than random variables).  If $z$ is a real number and $z_{n, N}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} z_{n,N} = z$ for all $N \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, can you show existence of a sequence $N(n)$ that increases to infinity such that $z_{n, N(n)}\rightarrow z$?

Comment: Nice suggestion. I have considered this direction at first, but then not pursued it as hard as I think I should have... I have taught a little bit more about it today and I think the following construction should do the job for a sequence of real numbers:

Let $N(n) = 1$ for all the values of $n$ such that $|z_{n, 1} - z| > 1$. And then, recursively, for $i = 1, 2, \cdots$, $N(n) = i$ for every $n$ such that $1/(i+1)  < |z_{n, i} - z|$. The sequence $N(n)$ goes to infinity since, for every $i$, we will evetually have  $|z_{n, i} - z| < 1/(i+1)$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another argument that combines Antonio's approach of dense sets with some of my comments:

**Given:**

Let $F(x)$ be a CDF. Let $S$ be the (at most countably infinite) set of discontinuities of $F$.  Let $F_{n,k}$ be a collection of CDFs indexed by $(n,k) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ such that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_{n,k}(x) = F(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus S, \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$$

**Construction:**

Let $D$ be the set of rational numbers in $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$.  Let $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots\}$ be an ordering of $D$.
For each $i$ and each $k$ there is some positive integer $G(i,k)$ such that
$$|F_{n, i}(x_k) - F(x_k)|\leq 1/i  \quad \forall n \geq G(i,k)$$
Define $G(1)=1$.  For $i \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$ define
$$ G(i) = \max\{G(i,1), G(i,2), ..., G(i,i)\}$$
Then for all $i \geq 2$ we get:
$$ |F_{n,i}(x_k)-F(x_k)|\leq 1/i \quad \forall n\geq G(i), \forall k \in \{1, \ldots, i\}$$
For each positive integer $n$ define $N(n)$ as the largest $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ such that $G(i)\leq n$ (such a value $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ always exists because $G(1)=1\leq n$). It follows that whenever $N(n)\geq 2$ we get
$$ \boxed{|F_{n,N(n)}(x_k)-F(x_k)|\leq 1/N(n) \quad \forall k \in \{1, \ldots, N(n)\}}$$

**Claim 1:** $N(n)\rightarrow \infty$.

Proof: Fix $j\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  Then if $n$ is any positive integer that satisfies
$$ n \geq \max[j, G(j)]$$
we have that
$$j \in \{i \in \{1, ..., n\}  : G(i)\leq n\}$$
Since $N(n)$ is defined as the **largest** value in the set $\{i \in \{1, ..., n\}  : G(i)\leq n\}$, we get  $N(n)\geq j$. $\Box$

Now fix $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. For sufficiently large $n$ we get $N(n)\geq 2$ and $k\leq N(n)$. So taking a limit of the boxed equation as $n\rightarrow\infty$ gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |F_{n,N(n)}(x_k)-F(x_k)| = 0 $$
This holds for all $x_k \in D$, from which we should also get convergence for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus S$.

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you a lot for the help and for this solution

Answer (score 0):

I managed to think of a tentative argument after Michael's comment. So I post here in case someone falls into the same question as me...

---

As Michael suggested, it is easier to start by **proving the result for sequences of real numbers**. If $z_{n, N}\in \mathbb{R}$ is a double sequence such that $z_{n, N} \rightarrow z$ for every $N$. Defined the following sequence
\begin{equation}
N(n) = \inf \left\{i:  |z_{\ell,i} - z| > \frac{1}{i} \text{ for all } \ell \ge n\right\}
\end{equation}

Except for the trivial case: $z_{\ell,i} = z$ for $\ell>n$ for all $i$; the set above can be empty (and $N(m) = \infty$) only for finitely many values. We can just arbitrarily replace these values without affecting the convergence.

Such a sequence goes to infinity. For an arbitrary $i$, we have that $|z_{\ell,i} - z| \le \frac{1}{i}$ for all $l \le n$, hence $N(n)>i$, for sufficiently large $n$. Moreover, $z_{n, N(n)} \rightarrow z$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

---

Now let $F_{n, N}(x)$ be the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the random variable $Z_{n, N}$. And let $F(x)$ be the CDF of the random variable $Z$. For every fixed $N$, since $Z_{n, N}$ converges in distribution to $z$, $F_{n, N}(x)\rightarrow F(x)$ at every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ at which $F$ is continuous.

Now, using the other direction of the equivalence, to show convergence in distribution of $Z_{n, N(n)}$ to $Z$ it is sufficient to show that $F_{n, N(n)}(x)\rightarrow F(x)$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ at which $F$ is continuous.

Since $F$ is a monotonic function it has at most countably many discontinuities, say, $\mathcal{S}$.
Now pick a countable and dense subset of $\mathbb{R} - \mathcal{S}$,  and call the points in this set of $x_m$. Define,

\begin{equation}
N(n) = \inf \left\{i:  |F_{\ell,i}(x_m) - F(x_m)| > \frac{1}{i} \text{ for all } 1 \le m \le 1 \text{ and }\ell \ge n \right\}
\end{equation}

using the same argument as before we have that $F_{n, N(n)}(x_m)\rightarrow F(x_m)$ for every $m$. The convergence in a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}-\mathcal{S}$ implies the convergence in all continuity points of $F$.

---

*Obs:* $\mathbb{R} - \mathcal{S}$ is separable (has countable dense subset) because metric spaces are hereditarily separable (see [If $X$ is a separable metric space and $M \subset X$ is a metric subspace then $M$ is separable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1355403/376104))

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  What if $N(n)=\infty$? Or, what if $z=0$, $z_{i,i}=100$, $z_{i,j}=0$ for all $i$ and all $j \neq i$? Then $N(n)=n$ and $z_{n,N(n)}=100$ for all $n$, it does not go to 0 as you say.

Comment: You are right. There is something wrong above. I still think the overall argument might still be saved tough...

For the case of real sequences, maybe re-define:
$N(n) = \inf \{i: |z_{m, i} - z| > 1/i \text{ for all } m \ge n\}$. I believe It would solve the counterexample you provided. It would still go to infinity by the same argument. Finally $N(m)$ could only be infinite for finitely many values, and we could just arbitrarily replace it.

Do you think this would work?

Comment: With the above definition, if $z_{m,i}=z$ for all $(m,i)$ then $N(m)=\infty$ for all $m$. What if we define $G(1)=1$ and for each $i\geq 2$, $G(i)$ is defined as the smallest $n$ such that $|z_{m,i}-z|\leq 1/i$ for all $m\geq n$.  Then define $N(n)$ as the largest value of $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ such that $G(i)\leq n$ (such a value always exists since $G(1)\leq n$).