# Ask the proof of The closure of the range of any compact operator is separable.

Tags: functional-analysis

The closure of the range of any compact operator is separable.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a compact operator from a normed space $\mathcal{X}_1$ to a normed space $\mathcal{X}_2$. Consider the set $\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))$ in $\mathcal{X}_2$ where $B(0; r) = \{x \in \mathcal{X}_1 : ||x||_1 \leq r\}$ and let $\{y_n\}$ be any sequence in $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$. Then, for every $n$, there exists an $x_n \in B(0; r)$ such that
\begin{equation}
||y_n - \mathcal{T}x_n||_2 < n^{-1}. 
\end{equation}

$B(0; r) = \{x \in \mathcal{X}_1 : ||x||_1 \leq r\}$ is the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin in $\mathcal{X}_1$.

The statement says that for every element $y_n$ in the closure $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$, you can find a corresponding element $x_n$ in $B(0; r)$ such that the image of $x_n$ under $\mathcal{T}$, when compared to $y_n$, differs by less than $n^{-1}$ in norm. In other words, no matter how small the difference you allow (as $n$ gets larger, $n^{-1}$ gets smaller), you can always find an $x_n$ within the ball $B(0; r)$ whose image under $\mathcal{T}$ is within that small distance from $y_n$.

Each $y_n$ is in the closure of $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$. By definition, for each $y_n$, there must exist points in $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ arbitrarily close to $y_n$. In other words, for any $n$, you can find an $x_n$ in $B(0; r)$ such that $||\mathcal{T}x_n||$ is within $n^{-1}$ of $||y_n||$. This is essentially what it means for $y_n$ to be in the closure: for any distance you specify, no matter how small, there exists an element of $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ within that distance from $y_n$.

The closure of a set $S$ in a metric space is the set of all points that are either in $S$ or are limit points of $S$. A point $x$ is a limit point of $S$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$ different from $x$ itself. In simpler terms, a point is in the closure of $S$ if you can find points from $S$ arbitrarily close to it, regardless of how small a neighborhood around the point you consider.

As ${x_n}$ is bounded and $\mathcal{T}$ is compact, ${\mathcal{T}x_n}$ contains a convergent subsequence.

It then follows from (4.1) that ${y_n}$ also contains a convergent subsequence, which shows that $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ is sequentially compact.

Equation (4.1) shows that for each $y_n$, you can find an $x_n$ such that $\mathcal{T}x_n$ is arbitrarily close to $y_n$.

Since ${x_n}$ is bounded (all $x_n$ are within $B(0; r)$), and $\mathcal{T}$ is compact, the sequence $\{\mathcal{T}x_n\}$ contains a convergent subsequence ${\mathcal{T}x_{n_k}}$. Let's say this subsequence converges to some point $z \in \mathcal{X}_2$.

Given that ${\mathcal{T}x_{n_k}}$ converges to $z$ and $||y_{n_k} - \mathcal{T}x_{n_k}||_2 < n_k^{-1}$ approaches 0 as $k$ increases, it follows that the subsequence $\{y_{n_k}\}$ also converges to $z$. The reasoning here involves the triangle inequality and the fact that as the $\mathcal{T}x_{n_k}$ gets arbitrarily close to $z$, and $y_{n_k}$ gets arbitrarily close to $\mathcal{T}x_{n_k}$, $y_{n_k}$ must also get arbitrarily close to $z$. This is a nuanced argument but essentially relies on the fact that if two sequences are arbitrarily close to each other and one of them converges, then the other must also converge to the same limit.

This step shows that any sequence $\{y_n\}$ in $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ has a convergent subsequence, which is the definition of sequential compactness. Hence, $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ is sequentially compact.

However, the fact that $\mathcal{X}_2$ is a metric space entails that $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ is compact and hence separable.

In a metric space, compactness has a specific meaning. A set is compact if every sequence in the set has a subsequence that converges to a point within the set. This property was shown for $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$
by demonstrating that it is sequentially compact. Every metric space is naturally a topological space, and for metric spaces, the notions of compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent.

Compact $\Longrightarrow$ Separable: A separable space is one that contains a countable dense subset. (refer to Definition 2.1.7) The compactness of $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ in the metric space $\mathcal{X}_2$ implies separability because in metric spaces, compact sets are always separable. Intuitively, a separable space is one that is “well approximated by a countable subset”,
while a compact space is one that is “well approximated by a finite subset”.

In view of the relationship $\operatorname{Im}(\mathcal{T}) \subseteq \bigcup_{r=1}^\infty \mathcal{T}(B(0; r))$, it follows that $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(\mathcal{T})}$ is also separable and the result is proved.

**Question: I don't understand the last step of the proof** from the textbook. I know why the relationship $\operatorname{Im}(\mathcal{T}) \subseteq \bigcup_{r=1}^\infty \mathcal{T}(B(0; r))$ is true, but I don't know the gap from there to the final proof that  $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(\mathcal{T})}$ is separable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $X$ is a separable metric space and $M \subset X$ is a metric subspace then $M$ is separable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355403/if-x-is-a-separable-metric-space-and-m-subset-x-is-a-metric-subspace-then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\operatorname{Im}(\mathcal{T}) \subseteq \bigcup_{r=1}^\infty \mathcal{T}(B(0; r))$, one can easily conclude that $\overline {\operatorname{Im}(\mathcal{T})} \subseteq \bigcup_{r=1}^\infty \overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$.

Now, note that $\bigcup_{r=1}^\infty \overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ is separable because $\overline{\mathcal{T}(B(0; r))}$ is separable for each $r \in \mathbb N$ (by using the fact that countable union of separable sets is separable). The conclusion follows by the fact that subset of separable set is separable.