# Representation of a cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

I am using the following definition of a cone:

> a nonempty subset $K$ of a vector space is said to be  a cone if it satisfies the following three properties: (1) $K + K \subseteq K$, (2)  $\alpha K \subseteq  K$ for all $\alpha \geq 0$,  (3) $K \cap (-K) =\{0\}$.

I think in $\mathbb{R}^2$ a closed cone can be fully represented by two vectors – let’s denote them as $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, -- in the sense that 
$$K=\{\lambda a  + \mu b, \quad \forall \lambda \geq 0, \mu \geq 0\}.$$

Once we move to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and higher dimensions, things become more difficult.

**Original question**: But is it correct to make a statement that any cone e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be fully represented/described by  a countable number of vectors (in the sense described above)?

**New question (after editing)**: Is it true that any closed cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be described as the closure of a cone fully represented/described by a countable number of vectors (in the sense described above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your new question is yes, but probably not for the reasons you want. Call your cone $C$, and pick a countable dense subset $S$. Why can you do this? A space with a countable dense subset is called 'separable'; $\Bbb R^n$ is separable (pick the rational coordinates as your countable dense subset), and [subspaces of separable spaces are separable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1197246/98602)

Now that you've done this, you have what you want, because $S \subset \text{Cone}(S)$, $C \subset \overline S \subset \overline{\text{Cone}(S)} \subset C$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.

That's not the case. Consider the cicular cone $K=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \ : \ z \ge 0, z^2 \ge x^2+y^2\}$.

If you try to represent it in the form you described with only a countable number of vectors, you won't be able to get all the points of the circle $$C=\{(x,y,z) \ : \ z=1, x^2+y^2=1\}$$

Comment: You are right. Let me slightly modify the question.